# How to save an entity with associated entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I load all categories in a list and then create an `Order` entity and set its `Category` property to one of those in the list. I set the `CategoryId` too.

Within the same dbcontext, I save the new order entity using a generic repository pattern:

```
public virtual T AddOrUpdate(T entity)
{
    if (entity.Id == 0)
        return Add(entity);
    else
    {
        return Update(entity);
    }
}

public virtual T Add(T entity)
{
    var dbEntityEntry = context.Entry(entity);
     
    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
    else
        dbSet.Add(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

With the above, I get the following exception:

> The instance of entity type 'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Using the context's `DebugView` I can see that all `Category` items have a state of `Unchanged`.

If I set the `Category` property to null, the order is inserted correctly.

Is there a better and generic way to save associated entities instead of setting them to `null`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Apparently the category is not attached to the `context` in `AddOrUpdate`. But why do you also set `Category`? Setting `CategoryId` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the list of categories from the database, it begins tracking them.
When you do `order.Category = categories[0]` (or any category of that list), it tries to track that category at position 0 and will try to insert a new category, therefore, just do it like this

```
order.CategoryId = categories[0].id;
```

Comment: Assigning a navigation property with an already tracked entity usually does not mark that entity as "added".